# Simulink Error: The overall system has unobservable mode in z=1

Tags: matlab, controls, modeling, simulink

I am using simulink to model a process with time delay, compensators and MPC controller.
Problem is when I hit the Simulate button I get this error:

MPC: Utility: Kalman1, Message = Problems encountered when designing the overall state observer(Kalman Filter).
The overall system has unobservable modes in z=1

The overall system Transfer Function is:

```
     0.2713 z^4 - 1.755 z^3 + 4.05 z^2 - 3.919 z + 1.353  
--------------------------------------------------------------
  z^7 - 6.21 z^6 + 11.57 z^5 - 3.192 z^4 - 8.476 z^3 + 5.311 z^2
```

Can anyone help with this error?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you create a minimal example you can share with us. If the error is still existing then. Otherwise you have a good starting point for debugging.